# Delete last n rows in mysql

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am trying to delete the last N number of rows in a given table. I tried running the following script

```
DELETE FROM SCHEMA ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 26000;
```

but I am getting this error

> Message: [SQL0199] Keyword ORDER not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH WHERE. Cause . . . . . :   The keyword ORDER was not expected here.

I also tried running this script

```
DELETE FROM SCHEMA WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM (SELECT  PID FROM SCHEMA ORDER BY PID DESC limit 26000) a );
```

but still, I am getting the same error except the keyword not expected was "LIMIT".

Are there any errors on my syntax? Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: SQL0199 suggests that you are using DB2, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is a DB2 error, not a MySQL error.  I would suggest:

```
DELETE FROM SCHEMA
    WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID
                  FROM SCHEMA
                  ORDER BY PID DESC 
                  FETCH FIRST 26000 ROWS ONLY
                 ) ;
```

I thought this would also work:

```
DELETE FROM SCHEMA
    ORDER BY PID
    FETCH FIRST 26000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Perhaps you are using a version of DB2 that doesn't support `ORDER BY` in `DELETE`.

Answer (score 0):

How to Delete the last n rows in MySQL:

```
START TRANSACTION

  SELECT
    @pid = MIN(pid)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT PID FROM schema ORDER BY PID DESC LIMIT 26000
  )
    last26000

  DELETE FROM schema WHERE pid >= @pid

COMMIT
```